# Converting circular structure to JSON error - while passing data from JS to CS

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to pass all the series in the chart from JS to CS using dotNetHelper.
But get error in this line "window.dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('Items', allSeries)". I tried different methods as suggested in other stack overflow answers but not able to get it to work. Would appreciate your input.

Error:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'u'
|     property 'alignedObjects' -> object with constructor 'Array'
|     index 0 -> object with constructor 'z'
--- property 'renderer' closes the circle
at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
at k (blazor.webassembly.js:1:5176)
at b (blazor.webassembly.js:1:1989)
at A.invokeMethodAsync (blazor.webassembly.js:1:3866)
at v.itemEvent (JSInterop.min.js:269:23)
at highstock.js:17:483
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at f (highstock.js:17:461)
at v.firePointEvent (highstock.js:270:1)
at C.runPointActions (highstock.js:307:340)
```

jsinterop.js:

```
function itemEvent() {     
    const allSeries = this.series.chart.series;
    //const convert = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(allSeries))
    window.dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('Items', allSeries); // Error in this line
}
```

ATComponent.cs:

```
  [JSInvokable]
    public void Items(List<Items> allseries)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter");// does not enter here
        foreach (var eachItem in allseries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("eachItem {0}", eachItem);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync` it implicitly calls `JSON.stringify()` and when the object you're passing has a circular reference it cannot be parsed so you get the `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` error.

e.g. Here the object is referencing itself with the `.self` keyword so trying to parse this object using `JSON.stringify` will lead to a circular reference error.

```js
// you can test this in your browser console
const obj = {};
obj.self = obj;
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

That means we need to ensure that the object we're passing via `dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync` does not have any circular references and is parseable with `JSON.stringify`.

To do this you can create a new object using the data you need from `this.series.chart.series` and pass the new object instead. *While ensuring the properties also do not have circular references*

```js
function itemEvent() {     
    const allSeries = this.series.chart.series;
    const simpleSeries = allSeries.map(s=> ({
        name: s.name,
        data: s.data
    }));
    window.dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('Items', simpleSeries);
}
```

[BlazorFiddle snippet](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/2pdr8bax) setup with a demo, check browser console logs to see the different behaviours.